# Truncating in Presto when zeroes appears after the decimal point

Tags: sql, type-conversion, decimal, presto, truncate

I am trying to truncate a decimal which has 2 numbers after decimal point in presto that should display on truncating the number without floating values and display the full decimal with floating values  when there are numbers from 1 to 9 after decimal point. I have used the following query but it does not do the job and still I am ending up with numbers having zeroes after decimal point.

```
select column1,case when right(cast(column1 as varchar),7)='.000000' then truncate(column1) else column1 end from table1;
```

Using varchar pads extra zeroes to the right and hence are the extra zeroes I have used in the above expression after the decimal point

Please let me know what has to done to truncate the decimal only when it has zeroes as the floating values

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want to display for a given number.  And if there are two positions after the decimal point, why does the sample code have 6?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `truncate(x) → double` Returns x rounded to integer by dropping digits after decimal point, but it is **double**, not integer. And displaying double without non-significant zeroes is a GUI job, it displays all of them or not displays non-significant zeroes. For example when I am using Presto Qubole,  it does not displays .000000 if nothing else except 0s after dot. So the problem is in tool you are using probably.

For example this works fime in Presto on Qubole:

```
with mydata as (
select 123.00000 as figure union all
select 123.0123 )
  
select case when regexp_like(cast(figure as varchar),'\d+\.0+$') then truncate(figure) else figure end
  from mydata
```

Result:

```
123.0123
123
```

But in your GUI it may not work the same because in second line is not integer, it is `decimal(8,5)`, wrap in the `typeof()` function and you will see, and GUI decides how to display `decimal(8,5)`.

You said:

> Using varchar pads extra zeroes to the right and hence are the extra
> zeroes I have used in the above expression after the decimal point

No, the result of your expression is not varchar, varchar is being implicitly converted to decimal or double, check using `typeof()`.

If you want it to work not depending on tool you are using, convert to varchar and transform explicitly:

```
select case when regexp_like(cast(figure as varchar),'\d\.0+$')  --all zeroes, change according to your requirements
              then regexp_replace(cast(figure as varchar),'\.0+$','') --remove fractional part
            else cast(figure as varchar)       --we need same type in case
        end as result
  from mydata
```

This will work guaranteed because result is varchar and displayed as is.
All that expression can be simplified:

```
--remove .0+ if no 1-9 after dot:
select regexp_replace(cast(figure as varchar),'\.0+$','')
  from mydata
```